# Gradle error Failed to resolve com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android, gradle

**

### Each time there is a problem: Failed to resolve.

Please help to understand this problem. Thank you in advance .

```
> 
Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Build Graldle App (UPDATED):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mkurbanov.lebap_kwartira"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.1'
// for experimental rx picker
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.13.1'
// If you have a problem with Glide, please use the same Glide version or simply open an issue
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
compile 'com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

root Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS
//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS//SOME WORDS

Comment: please share other build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

Try using in your gradle.build:

```
implementation 'com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee: master'
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had not added this in your other  build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```

if you had added then please post that build .gradle also

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the version number and that helped me. So, instead of:

```
implementation 'com.github.dev:Picker:2.4.6:video-activity-fix-SNAPSHOT'
```

I used:

```
implementation 'com.github.dev:Picker:video-activity-fix-SNAPSHOT'
```

Do not forget to run `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`